# Check availability of remoting interface asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc application, that relies on data being provided by a windows service. Its kind of like a video conferencing application, where the video streaming operations are provided by the windows service. The communication between the asp.net mvc application and the windows service is through a remoting interface that is created inside Application_Start method. The interface object is a static variable that is a part of the class derived from HttpApplication.

The video streaming service may be online or offline. Once a service goes offline and then comes back online again, I have to reinitialize certain state information in the asp.net mvc application.

What is the most reliable way to keep track of this. Should this be done using a background thread? Is there any other way to achieve this safely? The remoting interface exposes a Ping() method which returns a unique string to indicate that the service is online.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of information?

Comment: It sounds like you should be looking at implementing the [Circuit Breaker Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589784.aspx). I have never implemented it personally, but there is an example in the link, and there is another one in the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/).

Comment: @NightOwl888: Thank you. The pattern looks interesting. I will go through it and try out an implementation.